# How to give user access to GCP jupyterlab via "OPEN JUPYTERLAB" link in AI Platform console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, artificial-intelligence, rbac

... without giving access to everything in project with Roles like `Editor`.

Apparently giving access to `Notebooks Admin` is not sufficient. User gets 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that authentication for the notebook proxy that is automatically set up by google requires that user has access to use the default compute service account. So, apart from giving proper role like `Notebooks Admin`. You need to:

- Locate the default compute service account for your project
- Give user in question access to Role "Use Service Account" on the service account permissions tab.